Why I cant return null in this MySQL question?
LeetCode Question
Below is my SQL
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(num) = 1 THEN num ELSE NULL END) num 
FROM MyNumbers
GROUP BY num 
HAVING COUNT(num) = 1
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 1; 

Also i tried in another way,
SELECT IFNULL(num,null) num 
FROM MyNumbers
GROUP BY num 
HAVING COUNT(num) = 1
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 1; 

For test case below,
num = |8,8,7,7,3,3|
Since there is no candidate after HAVING filter, no rows will be displayed in my query. And, the expected answer for dealing with such case(no rows in answer) is like below,
|num|
|---|
|null|
Why my above two methods dont work? Can someone explain?
what exactly happened when no rows in column in the IFNULL(num,null) func, seemingly num is not null for no rows, then what's the evaluation of numin the IFNULL?

The HAVING clause restricts the results to count = 1. It only returns null when the count is not 1, so how do you expect it to return those?

Get rid of HAVING COUNT(num) = 1 since it's filtering out the rows that you want.

IFNULL(num, null) will never return NULL, since you have no  num=NULL in the table.

BTW, IFNULL(expression, NULL) is just the same as expression by itself. Use IFNULL() to convert NULL to some other value (e.g. 0).

@Barmar What do you mean by the same asexpression by itself? what kind of expression, i'm sorry it may sound stupid but its not very clear for me.

It's a placeholder for any expression. IFNULL(column_name, NULL) is the same as just column_name. IFNULL(LEFT(column, 5), NULL) is the same as just LEFT(column, 5).

First query:
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(num) = 1 THEN num ELSE NULL END) num 
FROM MyNumbers
GROUP BY num 
HAVING COUNT(num) = 1
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 1; 


As no group satisfies COUNT(num) = 1, HAVING fitlers out everything, resulting in no rows returned.

Second query:
SELECT IFNULL(num,null) num 
FROM MyNumbers
GROUP BY num 
HAVING COUNT(num) = 1
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 1; 


Similar to the first, HAVING fitlers out everything, no records returned.

Where a query returns no rows, IFNULL will have no rows to operate on, and will have no output.
Solution:
An aggregate function will filter for unique num, ensuring null is returned where no num exists.
SELECT MAX(num) AS num
FROM (
  SELECT num
  FROM MyNumbers
  GROUP BY num
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) unique_num

Result:



num




null




For the frist query, when no rows are left after the filter, why ELSE logic didnt work? it seems there is some hidden mechanism. Or maybe I should ask, no rows get selected is different from null? but whats confusing is when you wrapping around another func outside like you did in your provided solution, obviously, when you get no rows selected in your subquery, and ur selectclause in the outer query will take it as null? it just intrigues me how sql evaluated these stuff? and it looks very chaotic

SQL's behavior is rooted in relational algebra, where operations like GROUP BY and HAVING manipulate sets and subsets of data.
Row-level functions like CASE/ELSE and IFNULL:

Operate on individual rows
Depend on existance of rows
Cannot generate new rows

Set-level functions like MAX:

Operate on entire sets or subsets of rows
Do not depend on the existance of individual rows
Gurantee a single value is returned

